# Perl regex: why is the optional part not captured?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to capture matches where the last part is optional, but should be captured if present. But if it is optional using `(...)?`, it is not captured.

For example, with these 2 lines:

```
some text and number 18
some other text
```

I would like to always capture "some", and capture "18" if I see "number 18".

Using `/(some).*?(?:number (\d+))/`, works of course with the first line, but not with the second:

```
$ echo "some text and number 18" | perl -nle '/(some).*?(?:number (\d+))/ && print join("\n", $1, $2)'
some
18
$ echo "some other text" | perl -nle '/(some).*?(?:number (\d+))/ && print join("\n", $1, $2)'
$
```

But when using `/(some).*?(?:number (\d+))?/` to make the last part optional, the 1st match is always captured, but the number is not:

```
$ echo "some text and number 18" | perl -nle '/(some).*?(?:number (\d+))?/ && print join("\n", $1, $2)'
some

$ echo "some other text" | perl -nle '/(some).*?(?:number (\d+))?/ && print join("\n", $1, $2)'
some

$
```

How can I capture the optional part?

Comment: `(some)` matches 4 chars at positions [0,4), `.*?` matches 0 chars at positions [4,4), and `(?:number (\d+))?` matches 0 chars at positions [4,4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/(some)(?:.*?number (\d+))?/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cuQgPM/1/). Details:

- `(some)` - Group 1: `some`
- `(?:.*?number (\d+))?` - an optional non-capturing group that will be tried at least once, and will try to match 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
  - `number`  -  a `number`  string
  - `(\d+)` - Group 2: 1+ digits

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/Cdy3yX):

```
perl -nle '/(some)(?:.*?number (\d+))?/ && print join("\n", $1, $2)' <<< "some text and number 18"
# some
# 18
perl -nle '/(some)(?:.*?number (\d+))?/ && print join("\n", $1, $2)' <<< "some other text"
# some
```

Comment: Indeed, moving the wildcard part inside the non-capturing group makes it work. Strange...

Comment: @mivk It is logical, because the whole optional group pattern will be tried at least once, `?` is a greedy quantifier. `(some).*?(?:number (\d+))?` will only work if `number \d+` goes immediately after `some`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/cuQgPM/2). It happens because `.*?` does not have to match as it is non-greedy,the regex engine skips it, and goes to test the subsequent subpatterns. Since 
 `(?:number (\d+))?` can match 1 or 0 occurrences of the pattern sequence, and does not match at the current location, it matches 0 chars, and calls it a day returning a valid match of `some`.